# Make Mocked Static Methods Available for All Threads (or at least subthreads)

Tags: java, junit, mocking, mockito, junit5

I have the following code that I want to test using Junit5

```
public void myMethod() {
   final ExecutorService executor = ThreadsUtils.newFixedThreadPool();
   executor.submit(() -> {
      ClassWithStaticMethod.staticMethod();
   })
}
```

I wrote the the following test case

```
try (MockedStatic<ClassWithStaticMethod> mockedStatic = mockStatic(ClassWithStaticMethod.class)) {
            ...
            someObject.myMethod();
            ...
}
```

The above mocking does not work as per the the docs of mockStatic, the mocked static method's scope is only the current thread. However, how can we mock static method for multiple-threads scenario?

Comment: Usually when tests need all the bells and whistles to properly execute - it’s a first red-flag for the code that requires restructuring/refactoring

Comment: @dshelya: Since the world is not a perfect place many of us have to create tests also for code that is not perfectly structured.

Comment: mockito not support global multi-thread static mock on purpose, to avoid tests interfere with each other. but you can make custom MockMaker to achieve that, just copy classes in org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy and change the DetachedThreadLocal fields to normal Map